# App_Data folder not available in an MVC 5 project VS 2017

Tags: c#, macos, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

Am developing my first project on mac in  MVC 5 using Visual Studio 2017 , but am facing the following **problems**:

> 1.**App_Data folder is not available where i am going to place my Databases.**
>
> **2. An MVC has no initial template like that of a VS on Windows PC.**

*Below is the image of my VS 2017*

[image]

Comment: Looks like a normal 'Empty' MVC project template to me. Create the folder manually.

Comment: @GSerg, sure ?, i dont see any template in my project , is there any way of adding MVC templates ?

Comment: You select the template before creating a project. You already have.

Comment: @GSerg, i dont see it on this version may be i send you a picture

Comment: @GSerg, what am trying to mean here is , in Windows there's a common template which has a Navigation bar of Home, Contact and About , but here i have only a template with a word , how can get that template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, you can add it like on the image, maybe you can do the same thing in MacOS :

[image]

Comment: Man thanks for the answer , but why does the project doesnt show me the template which has Home, About and Contact, Here i just get just a template with one word , is there a way of getting that ?

Comment: Not at all! I am going to add a new answer in order to explain with images.

Comment: Ok @CoskunOzogul

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris sorry, I have posted an answer but that was for Windows. And I looked at my Mac, I have community edition of the Visual Studio and there is not the same options. May be in professionel edition.

Comment: Yes @Coskun , me too i have a community edition and it's like that you've said